# Ubuntu Login Loop Guest Account Doesn't Work Either 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with the Gnome and Lubuntu desktop environments.

Whenever I log in, the computer shows a black screen briefly, then takes me back to the login screen.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> shell terminals work, though. So does Lubuntu.

This is the `.xsession-errors` file.

```
Warning: Only changing the first 12 of 13 buttons.
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  157 (ATIFGLEXTENSION)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  66 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  23
  Current serial number in output stream:  23
Script for fcitx started at run_im.
upstart: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
upstart: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
upstart: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (12764) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (12754) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: logrotate main process (12661) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-release main process (12707) killed by TERM signal
upstart: upstart-dbus-session-bridge main process (12730) terminated with status 1
upstart: xsession-init main process (12746) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (12761) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (12780) killed by TRAP signal
```

Does anybody know why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please reinstall lubuntu-desktop through tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1). Hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 and enter your username and password. Then the following commands afterwards:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop

Finally reboot after reinstall completes.